# Yii и функция MySQL INET_ATON

Tags: php, yii, mysql

Решил реализовать в yii сохранение IP адресов с помощью функции `INET_ATON('$ip')`:

Ссоздаю БД

```
$sql='CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  Homeowners  (
        id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,                  
        ip INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,           
        INDEX (id)              
      )';
Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```

Запись в базу данных осуществляется следующим образом

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$sql="INSERT INTO `homeowners` (`id`, `firstName`, `ip`)
      VALUES (NULL, '$nameInput', INET_ATON('$ip'))";

Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```

Но каким образом теперь его доставать в формате X.Y.Z.T?

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Прямая вставка данных в запрос - прямой путь к sql-инъекциям. Также вы зря пытаетесь засунуть NULL в autoincrement-поле.

    $ip = new CDbExpression('INET_ATON(:ip)', array(':ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],);
    Yii::app()
        ->db
        ->insert(
            'Homeowners',
            array(
                'firstName' => $nameInput,
                'ip' => $ip,
            )
        )

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/database.query-builder

для обратного преобразования скорее всего потребуется функция `INET_NTOA()`

Comment: Код не работает, ошибка синтаксическая.

Comment: @Максим147, там забыта закрывающая скобка в первой строке, поправить не могу.

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев*

Для обратного преобразования IP-адреса из целого числа в формат X.Y.Z.T предназначена функция `INET_NTOA()`

```
SELECT INET_ATON('127.0.0.1'), INET_NTOA(2130706433);
+------------------------+-----------------------+
| INET_ATON('127.0.0.1') | INET_NTOA(2130706433) |
+------------------------+-----------------------+
|             2130706433 | 127.0.0.1             |
+------------------------+-----------------------+
```